# It was the first Sunday of / in December

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> 1. It was the first Sunday **of** December.
> 2. It was the first Sunday **in** December.

To me **'of'** seems like: **'possession'** and
**'in'** seems like: **'containing'**.

Sometimes we get to see:

> 3. Buildings **in** this city are so tall.
> 4. Buildings **of** this city are so tall.

This has always been a matter of confusion to me.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any real difference in meaning between sentences 1 and 2.

Regarding sentences 3 and 4, there is a slight difference.

- Sentence 3 implies that only some of the buildings are tall.
- sentence 4 implies that all building are tall.

---

However, the sentences 3. and 4 are not entirely correct, since some articles should have been used with "buildings", depending on the intended meaning.

The choice of article will change the meaning of "in / of" also, together with the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Sentence 3 is a commonly heard kind of generalization. No one would  suppose this accurately describes *all* the buildings in the city. It conveys the idea that so many of them are  tall that the reader is struck by the fact.